# Which threat level was Garou when he defeated Tank Top Master?

Tags: one-punch-man

As far as I understand, Garou got stronger during the series. How strong was he when he fought Tank Top Master? Which threat level was Garou when he defeated him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's already at The Dragon threat level as we know in the anime. He fights top tank in human form that means he's already on a dragon threat level.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before Garou defeated Tank Top Master and even afterwards, the Hero Association never considered him a real threat, which got Sitch worried, as seen in **Chapter 45**. So, no, Garou has no assigned threat level when he defeated Tank Top Master. It was not until **Chapter 83** that *the Association formally declared him as a Dragon-level threat*.

*There's no way to gauge exactly how strong he was when he defeated Tank Top Master* but seeing as he defeated several heroes successively in a short span of time, I'd say *he has, more or less, similar capabilities as that of higher ranked S-class heroes*.

Comment: To my downvoter, mind telling me what information I stated wrong?